# Which is The equation of a line for over the curve (ln(x))(ln(y)) = ln(xy) in point (1,1)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $(ln(x))(ln(y)) = ln(xy)$ in point $
> (1,1)$

---

I want to know if my answer is correct or if my thinking is wrong and the answer is finding using another way.
For the equation of the line, we have the formula: $y- y_{0} = m(x - x_{0})$.
Now We need to find the inclination of the curve:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}[ln(x)*ln(y)]
 = \frac{d}{dx}[ln(xy)]\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
ln(y) \frac{d}{dx}[ln(x)]+ln(x)\frac{d}{dx}lny
= \frac{1}{xy}\frac{d}{dx}\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}[ln(x)-1/xy]= -\frac{lny}{x}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{-ln(y)xy^2}{x^2yln(x)-y}
\end{align}

But ln(1) = 0, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.
In conclusion, my equation of the line is: $y=y_{0}$. So, $y = 1$?

Comment: $y$ depends on $x$, so you need the implicit derivative, not the partial derivative.

Comment: But I tried to make the implicit derivative. Where is wrong?